# How to assign a 2d array to another 2d array so that the output is a 4d array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a 2d array called "container" array in the shape of (3, 2):

```
container = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
```

I would like to insert 2d arrays called "solution" (such as the following) in the shape of (4, 5) iteratively into "container":

```
solution = np.array([[7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]])
```

Here is how the "container" should look like after the first iteration: a 4-d array with the shape of (3, 2, 4, 5)

NOTE:
The "solution" array is different in each iteration; only one solution is shown here.

```
array([[[[7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]],
 

       [[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]],


       [[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]])
```

I would like to use the following assignment for every iteration over the indices of the container:

```
container[i][j] = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `np.tile`

```
# repeat solution along container dimensions
np.tile(solution, (*container.shape, 1, 1))

array([[[[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]],

        [[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]],


       [[[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]],

        [[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]],


       [[[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]],

        [[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
         [17, 18, 19, 20, 21],
         [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]]])
```

If you want to use a loop, this works too

```
arr = np.empty((*container.shape, *solution.shape)) 
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        arr[i][j] = solution
```